# LG G4 USB PTP connection failure

Tags: usb, android, mate, shotwell, lg

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu MATE 18.04, and now my LG G4 (H815) won't upload photos to Shotwell over a USB connection. Up to and including Ubuntu MATE 17.10, I was able to upload using PTP mode, but the phone no longer shows in that mode. In MTP mode, it shows the old "can not claim the USB device" error, but unmounting doesn't solve it. I've tried a fresh install, and Gnome Photos can't see the contents of the phone either. Can this be fixed?